# Community website reference

Tags: discussion

Should we make a community wiki for references to websites? For example:

Hebrewbooks.org where you can search over 50,000 Hebrew books

Torahanytime.org where there are over 10,000 lectures by reputable speakers

etc... Good idea or no?

Comment: As in [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/essential-jewish-websites)?

Comment: @jake that may be a good question to post it at.

Comment: There are so many lists of Jewish links being maintained out there, including the two linked [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8021/2). What would be the benefit of this community trying to maintain another one?

Comment: @IsaacMoses maybe a community wiki would be good so people can just add and remove like it's their own.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in [jake's comment](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/710/community-website-reference#comment1518_710), we have [something like this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/essential-jewish-websites) already. Some of the links there (e.g. [these](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/essential-jewish-websites/8021#8021)) point to much more comprehensive lists that are already being maintained by other people.